# Android TableLayout dynamic data display is very time consuming

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am fetching 200+ records from the database and creating a dynamic table-layout view of it containing 1 image, 1 text view and 3 edit text for each row.

SQLite data fetching is very fast but the main problem is it is taking much more time to create the dynamic view.

I want to decrease that time because data can increase up to hundreds of rows.

Comment: use listview because ListView is lazy so it will aloocate memory for items that are visible on screen

Comment: How to use ListView here as i am having 5 different widgets with databinding in it @BirajZalavadia

Comment: of-course you can make your custom adapter

Comment: Can you send me a link or example of it as I am new in android and dont know how to make a custom adapter??

Comment: Look at this and try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text                                                                                                                                                                                  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html